# Airflow memory overloads and everything stales

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am developing a project using Airflow and I am having some issues. I have tried googling around but it didn't help. I think my problem is in conceptual understanding of Airflow so I am quite not sure where to start. I am hoping you could point me in the right direction after I describe what I want and what I am struggling with.

First of all, project requirements are simple:

- connect to the database and fetch N listings (MongoDB documents)
- extract listings image paths and load images
- process and upload belonging images to the destination

I should do these 3 steps as fast as possible on 8 core machine with ~19 GB of spare RAM. One iteration through these steps takes ~2 mins.

As I want to do it **as fast as possible** I have set

```
schedule_interval="* * * * *"
```

or in other words to **run it every minute**. Also, I want to run it using multiple processes so I am duplicating these 3 steps multiple times (for example 3 times). What I get is this form of pipeline **Start >> [Steps1, Steps2, Steps3] >> End** where Start and END are just dummy operators to connect running steps. And finally, I have set

```
max_active_runs=1
```

to run only one dag at a time.

After running it, everything **seems fine for a few minutes** but then, memory reaches almost 100% of usage and everything slows down and sales (tasks show **"Not yet started"**). I need to restart airflow manually to start processing again.

And here are my questions.

Am I doing something conceptually wrong here? Why does memory overload happen? I have a feeling that somehow Airflow does something in the background I am not aware of? Does it somehow start more processes than wanted or something similar?

Is Airflow supposed to be used like this? Should I fetch listings each minute and create a new pipeline with new 3 tasks or should I do it somehow different?

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.
Thank you all in advance

**EDIT:**

```
DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "retries": 30,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "depends_on_past": False,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="mongo_process_upload",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 3, 5, 10, 30),
    schedule_interval="* * * * *",
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
)

start = DummyOperator(task_id='start', dag=dag)
end = DummyOperator(task_id='end', dag=dag)

db = get_mongo_db().get_database(CF["base"])

collection_spider = db[CF["spider"]]
collection_send = db[CF["destination"]]

cursor_spider = (
    collection_spider.find(CF["spider_filter"], no_cursor_timeout=True)
        .limit(CF["number"])
        .skip(CF["offset"])
        .sort('updated_at', ASCENDING)
)

for document in cursor_spider:
    steps = PythonOperator(
        task_id=PUBLISH_TASK_ID.format(document['_id']),
        python_callable=publish_pics,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={"doc": document},
        dag=dag,
    )

    start >> steps >> end
```

Comment: Hi, What is the dag start date when you deploy the dag, also what is the catchUp flag set to.

Comment: I suggest you redeploy the dag with today's date as the start date/time close to your deploy date/time.

Comment: I will try that, thank you, but why do you suggest that?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem